# Where can I find the firmware for RHF2S001 gateway?

Tags: raspberry-pi, lorawan

I'm using this LoRa LoRaWAN Gateway - 868MHz Kit with Raspberry Pi 3 to set up a simple IoT LoRaWAN network.
https://www.seeedstudio.com/LoRa-LoRaWAN-Gateway-868MHz-Kit-with-Raspberry-Pi-3.html

I have just formatted the SD card with the lastest Raspberry pi OS image. But the firmware for the RHF2S001 gateway is missing. The link provided in the corresponding wiki seems to have a corrupt image. Where else can I download this specific firmware ?